# Show that f(z) is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that an entire function $f(z)$ is bounded in the closed unit square.

**My attempt**: I know that "entire" means analytic at each point in the entire plane. And I suppose that "unit square" means the square formed by $0$, $1$, $i$, $1+i$. I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

An entire function is differentiable everywhere. Differentiable functions are continuous, continuous functions on compact sets are bounded.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what "compact" means.

Comment: In this context just that it's a closed (and bounded) set. In other words, the closed unit square contains the line segments that make up its sides. The open unit square would be everything inside these segments, but not the segments themselves.

Comment: Closed and bounded.